# Spring+Hibernate, Autowire sessionFactory into hibernate DAO

Tags: hibernate, spring, autowired, sessionfactory

i have an *Hibernate DAO*, in according with *Hibernate API 3* and *Spring 3.x*, I use simply a `sessionFactory` and *NOT* an `HibernateDaoSupport`+`getHibernateTemplate()` - i hope this is a good choice... -

Now my *goal is to autowire `sessionFactory` into my DAO using annotations.*

In my `spring.xml` i have this:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="data" />
```

Inside data package i have all my DAO and Service classes.

This my simple `HibernateDao`:

```
@Repository
public class PersonHDAO implements PersonDAO {

 private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

 @Autowired
 public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
     this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
 }

 public List<Person> findAll(){
  return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("bla bla").list();
 }
}
```

I have no error during `spring.xml` loading, but `sessionFactory` still be `null`.

What i have to do?

**EDIT**

This is my `sessionFactory` declaration in `spring.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

       xsi:schemaLocation=
       "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <!-- <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" /> -->
        <property name="url" value="my/db/url" />
        <property name="username" value="myUsername" />
        <property name="password" value="myPassword" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="data" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="data" />

    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="transactionManager"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**EDIT2**
Now `sessionFactory` is not null, but i have another kind of exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [data.PersonHDAO] is defined: expected single bean but found 0:
```

Maybe means it can't find `PersonHDAO` bean?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Did you declare sessionFactory bean?

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="configLocation">
<value>file:src/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
</property>
</bean>
```

Comment: @Maurizio Cucchiara: sure, i edit my first post with some more infos.

Comment: It's a web application? Did you declare org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener inside your web.xml?

Comment: @Maurizio Cucchiara: no it's a desktop application i don't have a web.xml file.

Comment: How did you get PersonHDAO instance?
using AnnotationConfigApplicationContext?

Comment: @Maurizio Cucchiara: i simply create new istance: new PersondHDAO()... is this an error? And i initialize spring context using: ApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{"spring.xml"});

Comment: Big error!! You need to get PersonHDAO instance from the spring container :)

Comment: Take a look at http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.html#new-java-configuration

Comment: @Maurizio Cucchiara: oh... im very new with spring, now im read your link, thank you very much!

Comment: Now i have this exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [data.PersonHDAO] is defined: expected single bean but found 0

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is @Autowired

> ```
> @Autowired
> private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
 @Autowired
 private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

 public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
     this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create class

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@ComponentScan("com.your.package")
public class HibernateConfig {

  private Environment environment;

  @Autowired
  public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
    this.environment = environment;
  }

  @Bean
  public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.your.package" });
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(properties());
    return sessionFactory;
  }

  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class"));
    dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.connection.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.connection.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.connection.password"));
    return dataSource;
  }

  private Properties properties() {
    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
            environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    return hibernateProperties;
  }
}
```