# Refering bean from one jar to another

Tags: spring, jar, dependencies, autowired

I have 2 jars, common.jar and business.jar. common.jar contains common functioanlilty shared across all modules and most important it has hibernate session factory configuration like -
 .

Now, I want to refer mySessionFactory from common.jar to my business.jar because I am defining transaction information in my business.jar and transaction configuration needs HibernateSession info.

Please suggest me how to refer bean from one jar to another.

Comment: I would suggest to use Spring JPA if you can. If not try annotating your db helper class with `@Component` and autowire it in your business module, or try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128716/springhibernate-autowire-sessionfactory-into-hibernate-dao

Comment: It is not the issue with hibernate/JPA. I have a spring inbuilt class being used as a bean in my child jar.. when i try to autowire the class in my parent jar am getting exception.

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding the code dependency itself** (making the business module depend on the commons module for source code reuse purposes), I suggest you use a build tool (`maven` or `gradle` would be good candidates).

**Regarding DI**, you should define a configuration in the **commons module** (I suppose you already have this if Hibernate works fine in the commons module).

```
@Configuration
// other configurations for Hibernate, component scans, etc
public class CommonsConfig {

}
```

Then, in the **business module**, you should import the commons configuration.

```
@Configuration
@Import(CommonsConfig.class)
public class BusinessConfig{

}
```

Now the beans from the commons module should be detected by the component scan from business module (and you should be able to use `@Autowire` for beans from the commons module in the business module).

Comment: Thanks for your response. But whether there is any possibility achieving it via XML..
Say
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"> In my parent jar, how to autowire sessionFactory via xml?